# Seaborn lineplot using median instead of mean

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, median

I'm using `seaborn.lineplot()` to create a line figure like this (a line representing mean, surrounded by a band representing the std):

```
sns.lineplot(x="trial", y="rvalues", hue="subject", err_style="band", ci='sd', data=df)
```

[image]

My only issue is that since my data is not Gaussian, I care more about the **median** instead of **mean**. How to do that in Seaborn?

Or are there similar tools that  are capable? I know I can do from scratch in matplotlib but that requires a lot of work to make it this nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html):

> `estimator`: **name of pandas method** or callable or None, optional
> Method for aggregating across multiple observations of the y variable at the same x level. If None, all observations will be drawn.

> `data`: `datapandas.DataFrame`, `numpy.ndarray`, mapping, or sequence

Hence try the following, where `ci='sd'` must be specified.

```
sns.lineplot(x="trial", y="rvalues", hue="subject", err_style="band", 
             ci='sd', estimator="median", data=df)
```

If not using `ci='sd'`, then `estimator` should be a `numpy` method call, not a string.

- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
    
np.random.seed(2022)  # to produce the same data each time
df = pd.DataFrame({"trial" : np.random.randint(10, size=350),
                   "rvalues" : np.random.randn(350),
                   "subject" : np.random.randint(4, size=350)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7))
sns.lineplot(x="trial", y="rvalues", hue="subject", err_style="band", 
             ci='sd', estimator="median", data=df, ax=ax)
sns.move_legend(ax, loc='upper left', frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 31):

`estimator` should be a pandas method.

Use `estimator=np.median` instead of `estimator="median"`.

```py
sns.lineplot(x="trial", y="rvalues", hue="subject", err_style="band",
             errorbar ='sd',
             estimator=np.median,
             data=df)
```

Comment: `ci` is deprecated, for seaborn 0.12.1 it should be `errorbar`.